# PHP PDO rowCount() returning -1

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

I need to add a pagination system to my API. My database server is ODBC. My code looks like this:

```
public function pagination($query, $maxperpage, $values=array()){
    $query = explode('LIMIT', $query);
    try {
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($query[0]);
        $statement->execute($values);

        $result['row_number'] = $statement->rowCount();
        $result['max_per_page'] = $maxperpage;
        $result['page_nb'] = ceil($result['row_number']/$maxperpage);
        return $result;
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

But that gives me the following:

```
"pagination": {
    "row_number": -1,
    "max_per_page": "1000",
    "page_nb": 0
}
```

Why is the row number not working?

The query looks fine

SELECT lo_sit, lo_dep, lo_wrh, lo_addr, lo_rotcls, lo_asscls, lo_stotyp, lo_extcod, lo_blccod from G2001F.LOCMSTP WHERE LO_DEP=:lodep

and the values seems to be inserted fine as well

```
Array
(
    [lodep] => DEMO
)
```

$statement->rowCount() returning -1 makes no sense.

Comment: I guess it is an error. Have you checked following post https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#113608

Comment: First time I encounter a bug where the bug is not my fault lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the
> last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding
> PDOStatement object.
>
> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
> a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
> returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
> for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
> applications.

`rowCount()` is not guaranteed to work with a SELECT query, and it's not a bug. If you want to know the number of rows you should use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM G2001F.LOCMSTP WHERE LO_DEP=:lodep
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing.